Add direction bias to a fire spreading simulation with GLSL
I am building a very basic web based 2D fire spreading simulation. I'm using the game of life kind of algorithm to make the fire spread. The problem is that I haven't figured out how to make it obey the wind speed and direction. I obviously want to introduce a bias in the direction of the wind and I want the bias to be proportional to the speed of the wind.
Another thing is that I want the rate of spread to also depend on the amount of fuel at that location. The fuel load is represented by the colour supplied in the form of a PNG file. There are only 7 distinct colours.
Here is what I have in my GLSL fragment shader so far:
uniform int timer;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 wind;
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D veldt;

vec2 pos;
vec2 mse;
float pixelSize = 2.0;

void main( void ){
    if (mouse == vec2(0.0, 0.0)) {
        mse = vec2(-1.0, -1.0); // Take the cursur away from the bottom left corner
    } else {
        mse = mouse;
    }
    pos = vec2(
        floor( gl_FragCoord.x / pixelSize ) * pixelSize + pixelSize / 2.0,
        floor( gl_FragCoord.y / pixelSize ) * pixelSize + pixelSize / 2.0
    );
        
    vec3 colour = texture2D( texture, pos / resolution ).rgb;
    vec3 vc = texture2D( veldt, pos / resolution ).rgb;
        
    float neighbours = 0.0;
    float probability = 0.0;
    float status = step(0.5, colour.r ); 

    if ( step(0.5, vc.g * (1.0 - vc.b)) == 1.0 ) {
        // If the cell has some green or no blue
        for( float y = -1.0; y <= 1.0; y++){
            for( float x = -1.0; x <= 1.0; x++){
                float burning = texture2D( texture, (pos + vec2( x * pixelSize, y * pixelSize ) ) / resolution ).r;
                float windBias = dot(wind, vec2(x, y));
                neighbours += step(0.5, burning + windBias);
            }
        }
        probability = neighbours - status;       
    }
    
        
    // Fire dying
    if( status == 1.0 && ( probability >= 4.0 || probability <= 1.0 )){
        colour = vec3(1.0);
    }
        
    // Ignition
    else if ( status == 0.0 && (probability == 3.0 || probability == 5.0 || probability == 7.0) ){
        colour = vec3(1.0, 0.6, 0.0);
    } else if (status == 0.0 && probability == 2.0){
        // Add randomness
        if (step(0.1, fract(sin(dot(pos, vec2(12.9898,78.233))) * 43758.5453123)) == 0.0) {
            colour = vec3(1.0, 0.6, 0.0);
        }
    } else if ( floor(pos / (pixelSize*2.0)) == floor(mse / (pixelSize*2.0)) ){
        colour = vec3(1.0);
    }
            
    // Nothing happens
    else colour = vec3( status );

    gl_FragColor = vec4( colour, 1.0 );
}

veldt is the original map supplied as a PNG, and texture is the output of the previous frame retrieved from the framebuffer. The shader is being used through ThreeJS.
How do I achieve this? I am open to completely changing the algorithm to something that works, if my code cannot be rescued.
